# Passing python list as int * to C function through SWIG interface

Tags: python, swig

I have a list in python like below:

```
myList = ["apple", "örange", "banana"]
```

I am using **SWIG** interface and passing this **python list** a an integer pointer to a C API.

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Please post your code. What have you tried?

Comment: Why would you like to pass a `string list` as an `integer pointer`?

Comment: this is my list:
    `mylist = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]`
this is the C API getting called from python through shared object:
    `mySharedObject.xyzAPI(mylist)`
Now the C API expects a int * param but its actually a list.

Comment: @imaluengo Yes i would like to pass string list as integer pointer.

Comment: But your list is of strings :S how are you going to transform that to integers? casting a `char` to an `int` is not a smart thing. I mean, what do you expect to receive in the C program?